# What is the best way to look under Juliet's skirt?

Tags: lolipop-chainsaw

When I played Lollipop Chainsaw, I figured out the there were many upskirt moments. There is also an achievement for looking under Juliet's skirt by "accident".

What is the best way to do that? Will there be a punishment of some sort if I look under this cheerleader's skirt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stand idle for a couple of seconds, Juliet should stick her chainsaw into the ground. Just manipulate your camera to achieve your evil purpose. She will cover herself, simply push forward and she will eventually give up.

The achievement name is *"I Swear ! I Did It By Mistake !"*.

<sup>source : [XBox Achievements](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/lollipop-chainsaw/achievement/65098-I-Swear--I-Did-It-By-Mistake-.html)</sup>

Comment: I've not got the game but from memory (in a youtube video of worst/most pointless/why would you do this?! achievements) don't you also need to do it from behind?

Comment: I cannot be more precise right now, I'm at work ;)